# ERROR 1064 (42000) MySQL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES

Tags: mysql, reference, key

I never used MySQL before but I don't have choice this time. I've an error I don't understand. I try to create a table :

```
CREATE TABLE proprietaire(
    num_cpt INT REFERENCES compte(num_cpt) PRIMARY KEY,
    num_client INT REFERENCES client(num_client),
    num_commercant INT REFERENCES commercant(num_commercant)
);
```

I can't see my mistake. Could you please help me with this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, to enforce foreign key references, you cannot put the `references` as a modifier on the column.  You need a separate constraint for them:

```
CREATE TABLE proprietaire (
    num_cpt INT  PRIMARY KEY,
    num_client INT,
    num_commercant INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_num_cpt FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES compte(num_cpt),
    CONSTRAINT fk_num_client FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES client(num_client),
    CONSTRAINT fk_num_commercant FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES commercant(num_commercant)
);
```

However, your specific problem was the `REFERENCES` before the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

As a note: in most English-language databases, your use of `num` would be `id`.  `num` sounds like a count or "number of" something, whereas `id` is short for identifier.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was that REFERENCES was before PRIMARY KEY as you said.
I know, I call it ID when I designed database but this time I've got to follow what my teacher did.